# Parse XSD to get list of nodes

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

I have functionality giving users rights to edit xml messages. Kinds of messages is very much. Each kind has own `XSD`.
I'm looking some way to get list of nodes from `XSD` to make possible `drag-n-drop` transfer `required` node from that list to list of nodes of edited message.

The standard xml-validation just tells to user that message have not some required element but don't tell him about optionals

Is there way to simple parse XSD and get all nodes and their types (attrs, tag, etc)?

==============
Oracle version 19.6.1.0.0
XSD [examples](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QSAqjJ9_AWa1y5UFMyYGmeQOse2mihx1?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to work from source XSD documents for this, because it's very hard work to get it right: you want to work with an API offered by an existing schema processor. Some possible candidates:

- Xerces offers a Schema API for Java: https://www.w3.org/Submission/2004/SUBM-xmlschema-api-20040309/
- The Saxon schema processor can generate the compiled schema model as an XML file.

Comparing these, the Xerces API (as far as I'm aware) only gives you the content model of a complex type as a tree of sequence and choice compositors, whereas the Saxon interface also provides the finite state machines used for validating content models, so in principle you can follow through the sequences of elements that are legal for any complex type. With the Xerces interface, you'll need to expand the content models to take account of types derived by extension and substitution groups, whereas in the Saxon model, this expansion has already been done.